# ¿Cómo ubico un elemento a un cuarto del alto de la pantalla en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, xml

Buenas a todos! Tengo un RelativeLayout y quiero ubicar el centro de un EditText a un cuarto del alto de la pantalla, tal y como se ve en la imagen.

Sé que debe tener: `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, para centrarlo horizontalmente, pero en cuando al centrado a "la mitad de la mitad" del vertical, no sé cómo hacerlo.

[image: Imagen]

Mi código XML, por ahora es así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="derivadadx.juegodelnumero.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numInput"
        android:hint="@string/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

El `EditText`, como se puede ver, está centrado al `RelativeLayout`, el valor de los `ems` es el que se puso por defecto.

Lo que quisiera es que esté centrado a 1/4 del largo, algo así como "`layout_height/4`".

Comment: ¿Has probado con la propiedad `layout_weight`?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero ¿cómo la podría incluir?

Comment: Pon tu layout completo para verlo, layout_weight puede funcionarte lo que hace esta propiedad es dividir los tamanos entre el numero total que de la suma de todos los layout_weight es decir si tienes 4 edit text con layout_weight en 1 cada edittext usara un cuarto del espacio disponible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas.
Puedes añadirle al textview un margen superior del tamaño 1/4 del relative layout. Adjunto fragmento de código de una posible forma de hacerlo.
En este caso cogemos la altura del relative layout en el metodo `onWindowFocusChanged` ya que en el `onCreate` aun no está pintado y daría valor 0.
Aquí el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTexview;
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.el_layout);

    mTexview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numInput);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    // Aquí el layout ya está pintado y se puede coger su height.
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    posicionaTextView();
}

private void posicionaTextView() {

    // Alto del layout que contiene el textview
    int altoLayout = mRelativeLayout.getHeight();

    // Alto del textview
    int altoTexview =  mTexview.getHeight();

    // Posicion del textview centrado verdicalmente en 1/4 del layout
    // A la posición de 1/4 del layout se le resta la mitad de la altura del textview

    int posicion = altoLayout/4 - altoTexview/2;

    // Parametros layout del textview
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mTexview.getLayoutParams();

    // Al textview le pone un  margen superior para que quede centrado
    // verticalmente en la posición 1/4 del layout

    layoutParams.topMargin = posicion;

    mTexview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    mTexview.requestLayout();


}
```

}

Comment: Buenas! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
El código funcionó a la perfección, pero tengo una duda: Para ubicar el centro de mi `EditText` en el 1/4 del `Layout` contenedor, ¿puedo restarle a la asignación "`layoutParams.topMargin = alto/4;`", algo como `layoutParams.height/2`?

Comment: Sí claro. El código de ejemplo ubica el textview con su parte superior coincidiendo con 1/4 del layout. Para que esté realmente centrado en ese 1/4 del layout bastaría con restarle a su margen superior la mitad de la altura del textview. ACTUALIZADO CODIGO de la respuesta para ello.